# Alternative Storage Options

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, data-transfer

I have just started my wonderful journey into using a Raspberry Pi 2 device.

I know I could add an external hard drive to the device but my concept of just supplying a black box to my User will vanish.

I have noticed that the Android can support something called an eMMC module which acts as the 'hard drive' of that device.

Is there something similar I can use for the Raspberry Pi 2? Or is there another thing I can attach to this motherboard?

N.B. I am a complete novice to motherboards. Always been a software guy but now I need to learn it.

Thanks

Comment: Note that eMMC == SD cards; it's just a different form factor (guess what the [MMC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard#eMMC) stands for?), so technically the pi already has removable "eMMC" storage, albeit with slow access.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks. a learning curve that i am enjoying  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional storage only though USB or Ethernet, as these are the only external high speed interfaces available.

If you are looking for something small, consider USB flash drives.  You can get them up to 128GB, for a total of 512GB on a Pi.  Note, though, that its possible that you won't be able to use as many as 4 USB flash drives in the Pi if they draw too much power, but you're probably okay.

Another option for something small is a USB Wifi adapter - it is small, and allows you to remotely have access to storage on other machines on the network.  In that case, your storage is effectively unlimited.

Comment: Good alternatives  - especially the flash drive. thanks

Comment: I had a look at USB Flash Drives on Wiki. It seems to indicate that USB Flash drives are finite in the number of 'writes' (100,000). Would not a normal USB memory stick be better?

Comment: USB Flash Drive == USB Memory Stick = USB Thumb Drive.  Different names for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people connect spinning disks to Pi's via USB and even boot off them.  This probably requires external power if the disk is big enough.

Comment: Hi Bert. Thanks for your input - always appreciated. The trouble is that a spinning disc will be bulky for my final solutions.  A USB stick might be worthwhile looking at as a backup but I think I would need to store the info on another PC/hard drive. Still I am still reading up on all this :)